# Method to Prevent Workflow Foundation 3.5 from persisting an executing workflow

Tags: .net, workflow, persistence, workflow-foundation

Is there a way to prevent a WCF 3.5 workflow from being persisted?  I have an issue where some items in the workflow cannot be serialized so I need to block persistence.  Is there a way do this in .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set up a persistance store?  Or do you mean you have to be able to persist some but not others?

Comment: From what I'm reading, you must specify a persistence store if a workflow gets dehydrated.  I want to block all workflows from being persisted and must be forced to run in memory. That way, my workflows will never get persisted.  Of them are short lived (less than 5 minutes) and persisting causes serialization issues.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't set up a persistence store of any kind, sql or customized, all the workflows will stay in memory and you won't have to worry about the serialization issues.  You'll just have to worry about memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.config`, set `PersistOnIdle="false"`. This will keep your Workflow from dehydrating when idle.